# How to identify request came from servlet or not?

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters

I want to distinguish requested call coming from servlet or not?? If it coming from servlet then continue otherwise return false.

e.g if(request come from servlet )
continue;
else return false

Comment: A servlet handles requests and (normally) does not send requests...

Comment: A servlet is just Java code and could make HTTP requests if programmed to.

Comment: Are you redirecting the request, then you may set some flag in request attributes and check.

Comment: without adding flag is it possible??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are referring to an HTTP request, there are a number of HTTP headers that can be passed as part of an HTTP request. It might be possible to check that common headers are not set (such as user-agent, etc), but this would not prove definitively that the request came from a servlet.

So the short answer is `no`.

Comment: so is there any other solution??